# I need to disable access to the internet on my install of Ubuntu. How do I completely *remove* the wireless drivers?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, internet

I have a dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu. I want the entire device completely unable to access the internet wirelessly.  (But able to access it wired.)

My first idea was to remove the wireless card drivers, and I have already removed the wireless card drivers on the windows 7 partition. That was dead simple. But I can't figure out how to do it for the Ubuntu install.

I don't want a friend to install users of different access level, or attempt some "parental controls," or any nonsense like that. I just want to completely disable wireless internet on this device.  Activating "Airplane mode" is not a suitable solution.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more info on exactly why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The drivers are built into the kernel; I don't believe it's possible to remove them without re-compiling the kernel. There may be a way to disable them; not sure.

I'd suggest physically removing the card.

Note that people will still be able to insert USB WiFi cards, whether you remove the drivers or the internal card.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you wireless device with lspci -nn
2. To prevent the driver from loading use: 'echo "blacklist xxx" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf', where xxx is your driver name. It will blacklist your driver
3. If you later want to re enable it: 'sudo sed -i '/^xxx/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf', it will remove the blacklisting.

Please don't use the beginning and ending '' when using these commands.

Hope it helps.